# renderTemplate into outlet is not working

Tags: ember.js

I have templates `box/inbox.hbs` and `users/profile.hbs` with `{{outlet inbox}}` in `profile.hbs`

In my `profile.hbs` I have `{{#link-to 'box.inbox'}}this is a link{{/link-to}}` which should render `box/inbox.hbs` into the outlet `{{outlet inbox}}` which I'm trying to do in my `router.js` with:

```
Router.BoxInboxRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render('box.inbox', {into: 'users.profile', outlet: 'inbox'});
  }
});
```

but the link just redirects me to another page `/box/inbox`. How do I get it so that the `inbox.hbs` is rendered in the outlet on `profile.hbs`?

Comment: Could you provide JSBin?
By the way outlet naming without quotes will be deprecated Ember 2.0 so replace your {{outlet inbox}} with {{outlet 'inbox'}}

Answer (score 0):

I think the `link-to` helper is the source of confusion. As far as I know, `link-to` will always change the URL and route, so you would never be able to achieve rendering the `box.inbox` route into a specific part of the `users.profile` template by clicking a link unless you use nested routes.

However, to achieve something like clicking on a link to show the inbox content, you could always load the `box.inbox` route hidden using the named outlet, then on click of a link, show the div containing the `box.inbox` contents. Here's an example.

UsersProfileRoute:

```
Router.UsersProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this.render();
        this.render('box.inbox', {into: 'users.profile', outlet: 'inbox'});
    }
});
```

users/profile.hbs:

```
<a href='#' {{action 'showInboxAction'}}>click to see inbox</a>
<div {{bind-attr class=":inbox-style shouldShowInbox:displayed:hidden"}} >
    {{outlet inbox}}
</div>
```

css:

```
.inbox-style.displayed {
    display: block;
}
.inbox-style.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

and in the user profile controller have an action:

```
action: 
{
    showInboxAction: function()
    {
        this.set('shouldShowInbox', true);
    }
}
```